# environment variables on vercel with sveltekit

Tags: javascript, svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I have a run time environment variable `MY_ENV`, which I have setup locally and create in my cicd pipeline also.

I access this environment variable in my svelte app, using `$env/dynamic/private`, locally it works fine. But when deployed into vercel, the environment variable is shown as undefined.

```js
/** +layout.server.js */
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

/** @type {import('./$types').LayoutServerLoad} */
export async function load() {
  let my_env = env.MY_ENV;
  let my_region = env.MY_REGOIN;

  let BASE_SARAL_API_URL = 'api.saral.club/api/v1';
  let url = env.LOCAL ? 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1' : `https://${my_env}-${BASE_SARAL_API_URL}`;
  return {
    BASE_SARAL_API_URL: BASE_SARAL_API_URL,
    URL: url,
    MY_ENV: my_env,
    MY_REGION: my_region
  };
}
```

```html
<script>
/** someCompnent.svelte */
export let data
</script>
....
```

In my cicd config yml file, I am using `circle-ci`. I run the following sets of command:

```yaml
... 
   vercel pull --yes enviornment=preview --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
   vercel build --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
   vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
...
...
```

I tried with using `--build-env` option but it didn't work. I passed it as follows:

```yaml
...
   vercel deploy --build-env MY_ENV=$MY_ENV --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
...
```

I also tried, by setting up the environment variable in the vercel UI and making sure I run the pull step before, but that was also unsuccessful.

Basically, I am looking for help on how to pass my cicd environment variables such that they are available in vercel functions and it is able to render successfully.

Comment: Production behavior depend on your adapter. Which adapter you are using?

Comment: I am using adapter-auto, which in the logs I can see uses adapter-vercel

Comment: Well, then you can try using dotenv from npm.

Comment: Did you find a way to make this work? I'm interested as well and still browsing. Thanks!

Comment: No I didn't find a way to include the environment variables in CICD pipeline. Instead I created the variables in vercel GUI and using them in my svelte app.